# What is the node-id tag in kafka producer MetricName for and how can I get it from KafkaProducer instance?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I've have kafka producer running same code from 3 different linux servers sending messages to same kafka cluster topic. Below is the sample code -

```
    KafkaProducer<?, byte[]> producer = new KafkaProducer<?, byte[]>(props);
    Map<MetricName, ? extends Metric> metrics =  producer.metrics();
    System.out.println(metrics.keySet());
```

The sample of the MetricName produced by the above code -

> MetricName [name=request-rate, group=producer-node-metrics, description=The number of requests sent per second, tags={client-id=ImpLog, node-id=node--3}],
>
> MetricName [name=request-rate, group=producer-node-metrics, description=The number of requests sent per second, tags={client-id=ImpLog, node-id=node--2}],
>
> MetricName [name=request-rate, group=producer-node-metrics, description=The number of requests sent per second, tags={client-id=ImpLog, node-id=node--1}],
>
> MetricName [name=request-total, group=producer-node-metrics, description=The total number of requests sent, tags={client-id=ImpLog, node-id=node--1}],

So my question is what is `node-id=node--3` tag of the kafka producer `MetricName`.
Is it identifies the kafka producer instance uniquely?
If so, can I get it from the `KafkaProducer` instance? Because I  don't want to report metrics belongs to that different server from a specific server

Comment: `node-` + `-1` is the first node in your bootstrap servers, -3 is the third. You should be using clientId to uniquely identify clients. For example, add the hostname or ip to the clientid

Comment: @cricket_007 for bootstrap server `server01.kafka.qa.myorg.com:9092,server02.kafka.qa.myorg.com:9092,server03.kafka.qa.myorg.com:9092`
node--1 always represents `server01.kafka.qa.myorg.com:9092` correct?

Comment: I think it might be the last one (negative indexing), but should always refer to the same across clients using the same string